# QuizCreator: Whats the best way to safe Questions and Answers?

Tags: java, swing

I want to code a QuizCreator, but I don't really know how I should save the Questions and Answers. Would it be better to save them in one file or separate them into two files?

Also, how could I display the questions and then check if the answers are correct?

I am new to programming, I would greatly appreciate any advice you have.

Comment: It completely depends on the circumstances. Should it be a local app, a web app, a mobile app? You can do anything from saving it to files to using a database.

If you are programming a local app for learning purposes, I would probably save each question together with possible answers in one file. You could try to create your own file format + a parser for it, or use something like JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I would store them in a single file, and I'd use a file format like JSON. The file would look something like this:

```
[
    { "question": "What is your favorite color?",
      "answers": [
          { "correct": true, "Blue" },
          { "correct": false, "Red" },
          { "correct": false, "Green" }
      ]
    },
    { "question": "What is the airspeed of an unladed swallow?",
      "answers": [
          { "correct": true, "I don't know that" },
          { "correct": true, "42 mph" },
          { "correct": false, "10 kmh" }
      ]
    }
]
```

Then you can use a JSON parsing tool like GSON to parse the file for you. You'll have to read the file in, but you'll be able to find tons of examples of how to use GSON.

That's what I would do. Of course, you might want to use a format that's easier for you to parse.

```
Q: question 1
FA: 1
FA: 2
TA: 3
Q: question 2
...
```

Then you can just split the line at the : and see if it starts with Q (and new question) or FA/TA (false or true answers) assuming you're doing multiple choice.

You'll need to know how to open and read the contents of a file. If you use GSON, you'll spend some time learning how to use it. Otherwise you can read lines of the file at a time and parse them into your data structure yourself.

This is a pretty good practice program to write.

Comment: XML is also a good option. It has a simple syntax and can be read by eye pretty easily.

Comment: @Aaron yes, but all the parsers I've ever used are more difficult to learn to use than GSON.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion... keep it simple, keep it all in a single Text file regardless of what format you decide to use. One text file per Quiz. This way you can always re-use these files. As a matter of fact, have **everything** related to a particular quiz in that one particular file. Let the file do the work for you.

For some file examples, one quiz might be a Math Quiz, another Quiz might be on History, and yet another Quiz on Sciences. The rules for each quiz should be displayed to the student before any test starts. These Rules should be contained within each Quiz File so that all your code needs to do is acquire these rules from the Quiz File being run and display them to the Student before the quiz begins. Allow the Student to start the Quiz when ready (after reading the rules).

> An Example Math Quiz File (**MathTest001.txt**):

```
; QUIZ FILE - For the TimedQuestions class.

; The Quiz Message (optional) - This information is displayed to the User within
; a dialog box before the test begins.

; Quiz Message lines always begin with a Colon (:). 

; As you can see below, basic HTML can be used to make the dialog message.
; This can add some pizzaz to your Quiz Message.
; ONLY EVER supply one Quiz Message in any Quiz File! Feel free to copy/paste
; the below message from Quiz File to Quiz File.

; Message Tags (if you decide to use them) are optional and are filled by the
; application:
;
;   %flc    Number of Quiz Questions in file.
;   %sft    Number of seconds to answer each Question

:<html>Within this Test there are <font color=blue><b>%flc</b></font> multiple choice questions that need<br>
:to be answered.<br><br>You will have <font color=blue><b>%sft</b></font> seconds to answer each test question 
:unless<br>otherwise indicated above the question.<br><br>If a question runs out of time before it is answered 
:then that<br>question will be considered as <font color=red><b>WRONG</b></font>.<br><br>
:<center>Press the <b>OK</b> button to start the Test</center><br><br></html>

; As a matter of fact, the above message is default and the lines above 
; merely show how to make your own.

; Comment Lines always begin with a semicolon (;) and can go anywhere
; providing they are on their own line.
; Comment and Blank lines are always ignored within a Quiz File.

; MATH QUIZ QUESTIONS:
; The \n in Question Lines forces a CarriageReturn/Linefeed in Console. Format the
; questions as you see fit.

; Question & Multiple Choice Options | Correct Answer | Seconds To Answer Question
1: What is:  1 + 1 = ?\n   a: 1   b: 2   c: 3   d: 4\n|b|10
2: What is:  5 + 5 = ?\n   a: 1   b: 12  c: 10  d: 15\n|c|20
3: What is:  6 + 4 = ?\n   a: 10  b: 11  c: 12  d: 13\n|a
4: What is:  2 + 3 = ?\n   a: 3  b: 4  c: 5  d: 6\n|c|10
5: What is:  4 + 3 = ?\n   a: 7  b: 6  c: 5  d: 8\n|a|10
```

> An Example History Quiz File (**HistoryTest001.txt**):

```
; HISTORY QUIZ QUESTIONS:
; The \n in Question Lines forces a Carraige Return/Linefeed in Console.
; Question & Multiple Choice Options | Correct Answer | Seconds To Answer Question
1: Two of Henry VIII's six wives were executed. Anne Boleyn was one. Who was the second?\n   a: Katherine Parr   b: Jane Seymour   c: Catherine Howard   d: Lady Jane Grey\n|c|10
2: Who had his head chopped off in 1649?\n   a: James I   b: James II  c: Charles I  d: Charles II\n|c|10
3: When was William Shakespeare born?\n   a: 1554  b: 1564  c: 1574  d: 1584\n|b
4: The Merry Wives of ...?\n   a: Wandsworth  b: Wycombe  c: Walberswick  d: Windsor\n|d|10
5: Approximately how long ago was Stonehenge built?\n   a: 10,000 years  b: 7,000 years  c: 5,000 years  d: 3,000 years\n|c|10
```

> An Example Science Quiz File (**ScienceTest001.txt**):

```
; SCIENCE QUIZ QUESTIONS:
; The \n in Question Lines forces a Carraige Return/Linefeed in Console.
; Question & Multiple Choice Options | Correct Answer | Seconds To Answer Question
1: What was the Manhattan Project?\n   a: Golf Ball Invention   b: First US Satelite   c: The development of the Atomic Bomb   d: New York Housing Project\n|c|10
2: At what speed does light travel?\n   a: 12,000 miles per second   b: 186,000 feet per second  c: 186,000 miles per second  d: 186,000 meters per second\n|c|10
3: What is the largest moon of Saturn called?\n   a: Titan  b: CRT4  c: Quadra  d: Sat76\n|a|12
4: The molecule DNA is described as having which shape?\n   a: Sine Wave  b: Elipsicle  c: Tripple Spiral  d: Double Helix\n|d|10
5: Percy Spencer invented which time saving kitchen appliance?\n   a: Convection Oven  b: The Microwave cooker  c: Toaster  d: Refridgerator\n|b|10
```

You will notice that within each of the above Quiz Files there is a value supplied for each question which relates to the number of seconds a Student has in order to answer any one question. The code supplied below contains a mechanism that places a time limit on how long the Student has to answer the question.

And the code to utilize any one of these files as a console application:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TimedQuestions {
    private final String ls = System.lineSeparator();   // OS Specific Line Separator for console messages
    private boolean questionAnswered = false;           // Keeps track of whether a question was answered
    private int questionCount = 0;                      // Keeps count of number of questions asked to User
    private int rightAnswers = 0;                       // Keeps count of questions answered Correctly
    private int wrongAnswers = 0;                       // Keeps count of questions answered Incorrectly
    private final int DEFAULTSECONDSFORTIMEOUT = 10;    // The default question time limit
    private int secondsPerQuestion = 10;                // Current set time limit for question (can change by question)
    private boolean timeOut = false;                    // Keeps track of whether or not the question has timed out.

    /* If you are going to run this class on its own 
       through your IDE then supply the Quiz File name
       to the testFilePath variable below, for example:
       private String testFilePath = "C:\\Quizes\\MathTest001.txt";
    */
    private String testFilePath;    

    // Constructors...
    //================================================
    public TimedQuestions() {}

    public TimedQuestions(String testFilePath, int... secondsPerQuestion) {
        this.testFilePath = testFilePath;
        if (secondsPerQuestion.length > 0) {
            this.secondsPerQuestion = secondsPerQuestion[0];
        }
    }
    // ================================================

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* I like to start the application this way
           because I don't like the need for statics.  */
        new TimedQuestions().startTest(args);
    }

    public void startTest(String... args) {
        /* Get Command Line argument (if supplied) which needs 
           to be the path and file name of the Quiz File.   */
        if (args.length > 0) {
            File f = new File(args[0]);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                System.err.println("Quiz Error! The supplied Quiz File can not be "
                        + "found!" + ls + "[" + args[0] + "]" + ls);
                return;
            }
            this.testFilePath = args[0];
        }

        // Start the test...   
        if (testFilePath == null || testFilePath.equals("")) {
            System.err.println("Error! - No Quiz File Supplied!");
            return;
        }
        start(testFilePath);

        if (questionCount == 0) { return; }

        // Calculate and display score for test...
        double scr = (double) ((rightAnswers/questionCount)*100);
        int score =  (int) Math.ceil((double)rightAnswers/(double)questionCount*100.0);

        System.out.println(ls + "======================================================");
        System.out.println("Out of a total of " + questionCount + " questions" + ls
                         + "you got " + rightAnswers + " questions Correct and" + ls
                         + "you got " + wrongAnswers + " questions Wrong." + ls
                         + "Your score is " + + score + "% "
                         + "which gives you a grade of '" + getLetterGrade(score) + "'.");
         System.out.println("======================================================");
        // Done.
    }

    private void start(String testFilePath) {
        // Get the number of lines (questions) within the supplied Test file...
        int fileLinesCount = getNumberOfQuestions(testFilePath);
        if (fileLinesCount == 0) { return; }

        // Get Quiz Message from file (if there is any).
        String msg = getQuizMessage(testFilePath);
        // Display test information to the User via a Message Box
        // and allow User to start the test.
        if (msg.equals("")) {
            // Default Quiz Message in case there is none in file.
            msg = "<html>Within this Test there are <font color=blue><b>%flc" +
                         "</b></font> multiple choice questions that need<br>" +
                         "to be answered.<br><br>" +
                         "You will have <font color=blue><b>%sft</b></font> " + 
                         "seconds to answer each test question unless<br>" +
                         "otherwise indicated above the question.<br><br>" +
                         "If a question runs out of time before it is answered then that<br>" + 
                         "question will be considered as <font color=red><b>WRONG</b></font>.<br><br>" +
                         "<center>Press the <b>OK</b> button to start the Test</center><br><br></html>";
        }
        // Replace any custom tags (%flc and %sft) for their proper values.
        // The %flc tag holds the total number of questions within the test file.
        // The %sft tag holds the default Seconds For Timeout.
        msg = msg.replace("%flc", String.valueOf(fileLinesCount))
                 .replace("%sft", String.valueOf(secondsPerQuestion));

        // Display test information to the User bvia a Message Box
        // and allow User to start the test.
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    
        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (dialog, msg, "Test Information...", 
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  
    dialog.dispose();
        // If anything but the OK button was selected then quit application
        if (response != 0) { 
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // Open a Bufferreader to read in questions from the Test file.
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFilePath))) {
            // Iterate through the Test file and process one question at a time....
            String testFileLine;
            while ((testFileLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Skip Blank lines, Quiz Message Lines (lines that start with a 
                // semicolon [;]), and Header Lines (lines that start with a Colon
                // [:]).
                if (testFileLine.trim().startsWith(";") || 
                    testFileLine.trim().startsWith(":") ||
                    testFileLine.trim().equals("")) {
                    continue;
                }
                // Split the file line question into specific parts.
                // 1st part will be the question itself, 2nd part will be 
                // the answer and the 3rd part will be the number of seconds
                // allowed to answer question. If the 3rd part is not supplied
                // within the file line question then a default of 10 seconds 
                // is used as set by the defaultSecondsForTimout class global 
                // variable.
                String[] fileQuestionParts = testFileLine.split("\\|");
                String question = fileQuestionParts[0];
                // Allow for newline and tab tags within text string.
                question = ls + question.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n").replaceAll("\\\\t", "\t");
                //Get the question answer from file line
                String questionAnswer = fileQuestionParts[1];
                // If the seconds time out is provided within the question file
                // line then grab it for use.
                if (fileQuestionParts.length > 2) { secondsPerQuestion = Integer.parseInt(fileQuestionParts[2]); }
                // otherwise use the default of 10 seconds.
                else { secondsPerQuestion = DEFAULTSECONDSFORTIMEOUT; }

                String answerResult;
                questionCount++;    // Increment the questionCount variable
                questionAnswered = false;   // Set the qustionAnswered variable

                // Ask the retrived question to User....
                answerResult = askTimedQuestion(question, secondsPerQuestion);
                questionAnswered = true;

                // If the User entered then quit the test.
                if (answerResult.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) { break; }

                // If the Usert supplied input is the right answer then...
                if (answerResult.equalsIgnoreCase(questionAnswer)) { 
                    System.out.print("  CORRECT " + ls);
                    rightAnswers++;     // Increment the rightAnswers variable.
                }
                // If the Usert supplied input is the wrong answer then...        
                else { 
                    wrongAnswers++;     // Increment the wrongAnswers variable.
                    System.out.print("  WRONG " + ls); }
            }
            // Close the file reader.
            fileReader.close();
    }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            // Display file errors
            System.out.println(ls + "ERROR! - " + e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }

    private int getNumberOfQuestions(String filePath) {
        int q = 0;
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            // Iterate through the Test file and gather the number 
            // of file lines that are actually quiz questions.
            String testFileLine;
            while ((testFileLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Skip Non-Quiz Question lines...
                if (testFileLine.equals("") || 
                    testFileLine.startsWith(";") || 
                    testFileLine.startsWith(":")) { 
                    continue; 
                } 
                q++;
            }
            // Close the file reader.
            fileReader.close();
    }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            // Display file errors
            System.err.println(ls + "ERROR! - " + e.getMessage()); 
        }
        return q;
    }

    private String getQuizMessage(String filePath) {
        String msg = "";
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            // Iterate through the Test file and the quiz message if there is one.
            // Any file line that starts with a colon (:) will be added together
            // to create the Quiz Message (regardless of where it is in file). Make
            // your Quiz Messsage one of the very first things you place into the 
            // Test File.
            String testFileLine;
            while ((testFileLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (testFileLine.equals("")) { continue; } // Skip any blank lines
                if (testFileLine.startsWith(":")) {
                    msg+= testFileLine.substring(1);
                }
            }
            // Close the file reader.
            fileReader.close();
    }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            // Display file errors
            System.err.println("\nERROR! - " + e.getMessage()); 
        }
        return msg;
    }

    // Method for asking the questions retrieved from the supplied Test file
    private String askTimedQuestion(String question, int secondsPerCurrentQuestion) {
        // The secondsPerCurrentQuestion parameter allows you to change
        // the number of seconds for each question if seconds are
        // applied to a particular question within the Test file.
        // (See Test file information)
        secondsPerQuestion = secondsPerCurrentQuestion;

        // Establish a new Thread for perform our question timing...
        @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Lambda")
        Thread timerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("SleepWhileInLoop")
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // See if this thread has been interrupted. If it has then
                    // we stop our timer While/Loop (a gracefull Thread Stop).
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        for (int seconds = secondsPerQuestion; seconds >= 1; seconds--){
                            // Break out of this timer FOR loop if the question
                            // was answered by using Thread.interrupt().
                            if (questionAnswered) { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); break;}
                            // Show that timer is ticking away...
                            System.out.print("*");

                            // ==========================================================
                            // Or you can use this...
                            //if (seconds < secondsForTimout) { System.out.print("-"); }
                            //System.out.print(seconds);
                            // ==========================================================
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }

                        // If the question wasn't answered and our timer loop has 
                        // expired then inform User that time is up and set the
                        // timeOut variable to true.
                        if (!questionAnswered) { 
                            System.out.print("\b\b\b\Your time is up for this question!");
                            timeOut = true; 
                        } 
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });

        // Catch Exceptions for BufferReader()/InputStreamReader()...
        try {
            // Declare a BufferReader object so as to get input from User.
            // We use BufferReader along with InputStreamReader(System.in) 
            // for this.
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

           // Display the supplied Question from file to User...
           if (questionCount > 1) {
                System.out.println(ls + "------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            System.out.print("[" + secondsPerQuestion + " seconds]");
            System.out.println(question);

            // Declare User input variable & initialize to a Null String
            String input = "";      

            // Reset the timeOut variable
            timeOut = false;    

            // Make sure our timer thread is dead before restarting it.
            //while (timerThread.isAlive()){}
            // Start the Timer Thread
            if (secondsPerQuestion > 0) { timerThread.start(); }

            // Loop through input from the User
            do {
                // Wait until we have User input data to complete a readLine()
                // or until our timer thread has set the timeOut variable to
                // true.
                while (!br.ready()) {
                    // If our timer thread has set the timeOut variable to
                    // true then let's get outta this question altogether.
                    // First we get out of our 'wait for input' loop...
                    if (secondsPerQuestion > 0 && timeOut) { break; }
                }
                // Then we get out of our Do/While Loop.
                if (secondsPerQuestion > 0 && timeOut) { break; }

                // No time-out so let's move on...
                // Let's see what the User supplied for an answer.
                // If just ENTER was supplied then input will contain
                // a Null String and the User can still enter an answer
                // until the question is timed out.
                input = br.readLine(); 

                // remove any unwanted text from System.out.print() 
                // that had made its way through the timer thread.
                System.out.print("\b\b\b\b\b");
            } while ("".equals(input));

            // Stop the timer thread.
            timerThread.interrupt();

            return input;
        }
        catch (IOException ex) { return ""; }
    }

    // Determine & return the Letter Grade for the 
    // supplied integer test percentage score. This
    // is a typical North American Standard (I think?).
    private String getLetterGrade(int score) {
        String grade = "";
        if (score >= 90) { grade = "A"; }
        if (score >= 80 && score <= 89) { grade = "B"; }
        if (score >= 70 && score <= 79) { grade = "C"; }
        if (score >= 60 && score <= 69) { grade = "D"; }
        if (score >= 0 && score <= 59) { grade = "F"; }
        return grade;
    }

    public int getSecondsPerQuestion() {
        return secondsPerQuestion;
    }

    public void setSecondsPerQuestion(int secondsPerQuestion) {
        this.secondsPerQuestion = secondsPerQuestion;
    }

    public String getTestFilePath() {
        return testFilePath;
    }

    public void setTestFilePath(String testFilePath) {
        this.testFilePath = testFilePath;
    }

    public boolean isQuestionAnswered() {
        return questionAnswered;
    }

    public int getQuestionCount() {
        return questionCount;
    }

    public int getRightAnswers() {
        return rightAnswers;
    }

    public int getWrongAnswers() {
        return wrongAnswers;
    }

    public int getDEFAULTSECONDSFORTIMEOUT() {
        return DEFAULTSECONDSFORTIMEOUT;
    }

}
```

You can use the above class on its own or add it to another project.

**To use on its own within your IDE:**

- Create a new Project named TimedQuestions;
- Create a new Java Class named TimedQuestions;
- Copy/paste the above code into the new Class;
- Modify the **private String testFilePath;** class member variable to
  **private String testFilePath = "Your_Quiz_path_And_File_Name";**
- Run the project.

**To use within an existing Java Project:**

- Create a new Java Class named TimedQuestions within your project;
- Copy/paste the above code into the new Class;
- Somewhere within your project code activate the class:

  ```
  TimedQuestions tq = new TimedQuestions();
  tq.startTest("C:\\Quizes\\ScienceTest001.txt");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question and it requires an answer with some amount of opinion.

**To address your first concern:**

Before you being programming, you should separate the questions and answers into two separate files.  One file for questions, one file for answers.  Both files should be indexed 1 to N.  Also, you should mark each answer to indicate which question it belongs to, and you should mark each answer with incorrect or correct.

Common file types like .txt or .csv are fine (Notepad, Excel).  Database systems are good too, but they are more complex (MS SQL, MySql).

**How to program the game:**

Once this is done, you can use a common programming language like Java to access the question-file and access and display question by line-number.  Then, you can access the answer-file and display all associated answers.

Next, you will prompt the user to make an answer-choice.  Using the user's response, you will compare it against the correct answer's index.  If they are the same, the user has selected correctly.  If not, the user's answer is wrong.  Whatever the case, you return the result of the user's decision to them.

The **actual implantation** of this code is pretty straightforward.  You will need statements like:

- read from file
- read from console
- write to console
- if and else statements

You can find all the documentation for these statements at [Java Tutorials](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java/)

Comment: This implementation is messy. Why bother keeping track of two separate files when you can create a simple parsing structure in a single file? The answer by Joseph Larson is much simpler and easier to implement well.

Comment: @Aaron I disagree.  Consider the audience to this answer, they are new to programming.  Did you start your CS curriculum parsing JSON-files?  This implementation is simple and modular, it allows OP to tackle each part of the problem in separate, manageable, steps.

Comment: He also suggested writing a simple loop to parse a custom single-file syntax. Read his entire answer.

Comment: @Aaron you're right, one file of a custom syntax is simpler.  I'm going to leave my answer here because it's a good example to OP on the importance of design decisions.

Comment: Fair enough. More options for solutions is better.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph's answer is pretty good, and you can definitely use his suggestions to great effect. That said, another option is XML. There's a great tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm) that breaks it down pretty nicely. I suggest you take a look at it.

You could structure your XML something like this:

```
<quiz>
   <question type="mc">
      <prompt>What color is an orange?</prompt>
      <a>orange</a>
      <b>blue</b>
      <c>red</c>
      <d>yellow</d>
      <answer> a </answer>
   </question>

   <question type="mc">
      <prompt>What color is a banana?</prompt>
      <a>orange</a>
      <b>blue</b>
      <c>red</c>
      <d>yellow</d>
      <answer> d </answer>
   </question>

 <question type="tf">
      <prompt>The sky is blue</prompt>
      <a>true</a>
      <b>false</b>
      <answer> a </answer>
  </question>


</quiz>
```

Of course, you could structure this however you want. But its a good way to get used to the nature of Java while also integrating a robust and customizable solution into your project.